# How do I convert a python list comprehension to a map/filter function calls?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have some python code that looks like this:

```
return [x.doSomething() for x in getIterator() if x[0]=="z"]
```

How do I get the same functionality with `map()` and `filter()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The translation would be

```
return map(lambda x: x.doSomething(), 
           filter(lambda x: x[0] == "z", getIterator()))
```

But, please, use the list comprehension.  It's faster, more concise and more readable.